# Service Worker fetch event doesn't intercept network calls

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

I'm trying to intercept network requests using a service worker. I have the most straightforward setup for this, which is an `index.html` file and `sw.js` files:

```
- index.html
- sw.js


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
      .then((reg) => {
        console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
      })

  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos')
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And my service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function () {
  return self.skipWaiting()
})

self.addEventListener('activate', async function (event) {
  return self.clients.claim()
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  debugger
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
      )
  );
});
```

I'm running a local server, and I see in the console the registration message:

> Registration succeeded. Scope is http://localhost:5000/

But I don't hit the debugger. I tried to refresh, open a new tab, or make the request upon click, but nothing isn't working.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I am able to hit the dubugger using above code. its working as expected. Let me know if any help needed.